# Devise Redirect if User Already Logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, devise

I currently have it set so that the root is a "informational landing page" with a login & signup button that direct to "/login" and "/signup". I already have it set so that it redirects to root if user is not logged in and it tries to load a page that need identification. I want to make it so that if the user is already logged in it redirects to "/home".

**My question** is how would I make it so that it redirects to /home when you load the root page if the user is already logged in.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the root page controller, add a `before_action` (Rails 4) / `before_filter` (Rails 3) which checks whether or not the User is signed in.

`root_controller.rb`

```
before_action :check_signed_in

def check_signed_in
  redirect_to home_path if signed_in?
end
```

Comment: Excactly what I was looking for! You just saved me hours of mundane research. Thanks!